# Not able to access Odoo custom model with API

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am new to odoo. My requirement is to add few custom models to odoo and communicate to those models through odoo api. I want through multiple tutorials for how to create new model in odoo.

Followed link (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html) to create new module and create new model in it. I am able to create module named 'openacademy' as suggested and also I am able to see on the odoo UI.

Following is the model I have created.

```
from openerp import models, fields

class LessMinimalModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.model2'

    name = fields.Char()
```

But when I am trying webservice from my Django project with the object name 'test.model2', it is giving error "Object test.model2 doesn't exist".

Am I missing something here? Is there something needs to be configured to access through API ?

**Edit:**
I have installed the module and model is also getting shown under Database Structure - > Models as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart server and update your module.

Before that your py files must be added in `__init__.py`.

Go to `Settings -> Update Module List`

Then `Settings -> Installed Modules` remove filtration and search your module and install it.

Once your module installed your model will be created.

Comment: I have also installed that module and it is coming in the models list under Database Structure - > Models. But still I am getting same error -   "Object test.model2 doesn't exist"

Comment: @Niraj Chapla  Have to try update all modules using below command in your terminal   -u all -d <database name>

Comment: Not sure how but updating the all modules worked.  And now after any changes it gets effected bu just upgrading that module